# How to use typeof to get "runtime" type of an object?

Tags: typescript

I want to get type of object with already declared keys/values.
I have following code:

```
interface ConfigVar<T extends 'string' | 'number' | 'boolean'> {
  env: string;
  type: T;
}

interface ConfigMap {
  [key: string]: ConfigVar<'string'> | ConfigVar<'number'> | ConfigVar<'boolean'>;
}

type ConfigType<T extends ConfigMap> = {
  [P in Extract<keyof T, string>]:
    T[P] extends ConfigVar<'string'> ? string :
    T[P] extends ConfigVar<'boolean'> ? boolean :
    T[P] extends ConfigVar<'number'> ? number :
    never;
};

// usage

const configMap: ConfigMap = {
  var1: {
    env: 'VAR1',
    type: 'string',
  },
};

type ConfigMapType = ConfigType<typeof configMap>;

const config: ConfigMapType = {
  var1: true, // Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'
  // var1: 'str', // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
};
```

My goal is to make `ConfigMapType` allow only `{ var1: string }`. Is that possible with typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditional types are ok, the only problem you have is preserving the actual type of `configMap`. if you have an explicit type annotation that will be the final type of the variable and the type of the object literal will not play into it. The best way to keep both the constraint and infer the type from the object literal is to use a generic function :

```
interface ConfigVar<T extends 'string' | 'number' | 'boolean'> {
  env: string;
  type: T;
}

interface ConfigMap {
  [key: string]: ConfigVar<'string'> | ConfigVar<'number'> | ConfigVar<'boolean'>;
}

type ConfigType<T extends ConfigMap> = {
  [P in Extract<keyof T, string>]:
    T[P] extends ConfigVar<'string'> ? string :
    T[P] extends ConfigVar<'boolean'> ? boolean :
    T[P] extends ConfigVar<'number'> ? number :
    never;
};

// usage

const configMap = (<T extends ConfigMap>(o:T)=> o)({
  var1: {
    env: 'VAR1',
    type: 'string',
  },
});

type ConfigMapType = ConfigType<typeof configMap>;

const config: ConfigMapType = {

  var1: 'str
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `configMap` and `var1` are the values, not types. Therefore, TypeScript cannot verify it. You need to put `var1` in one of the type definition, somewhere, like:

```
type ConfigMapType = ConfigType<{ var1: ConfigVar<'string'> }>;
```

or

```
interface ConfigVar<T extends 'string' | 'number' | 'boolean' = 'string'> {
    env: string;
    type: T;
}

type ConfigType<T> = {
    [P in Extract<keyof T, string>]:
    T[P] extends ConfigVar<'string'> ? string :
    T[P] extends ConfigVar<'boolean'> ? boolean :
    T[P] extends ConfigVar<'number'> ? number :
    never;
};

const configMap = {
    var1: <ConfigVar>{
        env: 'VAR1',
        type: 'string',
    },
};

type ConfigMapType = ConfigType<typeof configMap>;

const config: ConfigMapType = {
    var1: 'string',
};
```